# UK: Immigration & Visa Laws - how to be a freelancer?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, freelance

I know the Student Visa blocks self-employment, but what about other visas in the UK? Is it possible to have two visas at once, or have some visa that allows both university studies and freelancing?

Edit: I have posted a more detailed question about this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have two visas at once.  If you have a visa that allows you to work, however, you can also study on the side.  There is a list of such visas available at https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/appendix-student

ST 26.5. A Student is not allowed to do any of the following:

(a) be self-employed or engage in business activity unless ST 26.8 applies;

ST 26.8. A Student may be self-employed, if:

(a) they have applied for permission on the Start-up route; and

(b) that application is supported by an endorsement from a Start-up route endorsing body which is a higher education provider with a track record of compliance; and

(c) the application was made when the applicant had permission as a Student; and

(d) a decision has not been made on the application, or where the application has been refused, any Administrative Review against a refusal has not been finally determined.